# Syntax error when using vitest on my component test

Tags: javascript, vite, vitest, solid-js

I created a test to test the working of one of my buttons designed in solidjs using `vitest` and `solid-testing-library`. Here is my basic test:

```
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from 'solid-testing-library';
import { Messenger } from '../Messenger';

test('changes text on click', async () => {
  await render(() => <Messenger />);
  const component = await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Click me!' });
  expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(component);
  expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Test this!' })).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

it tests the operation of a button at the rendering level after the click. The default value of the name attribute is *Click me!* but after a click, this attribute takes the value *Test this!* .However, `vitest` didn't recognize this test, so I modified it like this, inspired by this [example](https://github-com.translate.goog/solidjs/templates/blob/master/ts-vitest/src/todo-list.test.tsx?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=op,sc):

```
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from 'solid-testing-library';
import { describe, expect,it ,  test } from 'vitest';
import { Messenger } from '../components/header/Messenger';

describe('<Messenger />', () => {
  test('This changes text on click', () => {
  const { component } = render(() => <Messenger />);
  expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Click me!' }));
  expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(component);
  expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Test this!' })).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

})
```

The problem is that when I run I get the error:

```
 SyntaxError: C:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\w3\front\src\__tests__\test.test.jsx: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (9:9)    
    
       7 |   test('This changes text on click', () => {
       8 |   const { component } = render(() => <Messenger />);
    >  9 |   expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Click me!' }));
```

To solve this problem, after looking on this [article](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/testing-with-vitest), I modified my test file like this:

```
describe('<Messenger />', () => {
  it('create an instance', () => {
  const { component } = render(() => <Messenger />);
  expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Click me!' }));
  expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
  });


  it('This changes text on click', () => {
    const { component } = render(() => <Messenger />);
    expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(component);
    expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Test this!' })).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  
})
```

But I still get the exact same error. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `async` keyword to the test function definition:

```
//                    here v
it('create an instance', async () => {
  const { component } = render(() => <Messenger />);
  expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Click me!' }));
  expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```